# Inject @Resource into normal class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, code-injection

I am using glassfish v3 where I created a JavaMail session through the admin console. I want to use the Mail session like this:

```
....
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class Mailer {

    MailGenerator mailGenerator;
    @Resource(name = "mail/WMCMail")
    private Session mailSession;

    public Mailer(MailGenerator mailGenerator) {
        this.mailGenerator = mailGenerator;
    }

    public void sendMixedMail(String recipient, String subject) {
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            message.setRecipients(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(recipient, false));
            message.setSubject(subject);

            ......

            Transport.send(message);

            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Mail sent to {0}.", recipient);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error in sending email to " + recipient, ex);
        } 
    }
}
```

When I call the sendMixedMail method I see that the mailSession is null. Is it not possible to inject a Resource into a normal class? And when I say normal I mean a class which is not a managed bean or a ejb-something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do that for a normal class. Quoting from [SUN's J2EE injection page](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/injection/):

> Keep in mind that a Java EE 5 platform
>   container can handle the injections
>   transparently only when they are used
>   on container-managed components, such
>   as EJB beans, Servlets, and JavaServer
>   Pages (JSP) technology tag handlers.
>
> This is for two reasons. First, for
>   performance considerations, a
>   container can restrict its search of
>   annotations only to the components it
>   manages, which are defined in a
>   deployment descriptor or are
>   accessible in specific classpath
>   locations. Second, the container must
>   have control over the creation of the
>   component to be able to transparently
>   perform the injection into the
>   component.